# making a software router for my private network

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, centos, routing, nat

give me suggestion on this problem.
I have 2 nic cards public ip (eth1) and private ip (eth2). now i have a linux system having centos 6.4. I made this system software router so can access internet on my client system.
and it working properly.

for previous software router i do natting like this.

```
iptables -F
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -t mangle -F
iptables -X
iptables -t  nat -X
iptables -t mangle -X
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth2 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -j ACCEPT
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
service iptables save
service iptables restart
```

and it work fine i am able to access internet over client system.

but now i want to attach 3 nic card (eth3) in same system for public ip as well and want my client system access internet through that public ip also. In this case what will i do.
and one thing i also want that if any case my one service provider gets down that time i want to up another service provider. in that case what to do.

for this tell me  the proper way so can build this successfully.